# Auto.VR and Lo.Mac, decision rule?

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to decide if a certain series follows a random walk by using Automatic Variance Ratio test (`Auto.VR`) and Lo-MacKinlay Variance Ratio Tests (`Lo.Mac`).

If we consider below mentioned examples, what would the decision be?
(Null Hypothesis: r is serially uncorrelated.)

```
data(exrates)    
y <- exrates$ca                               
nob <- length(y)
r <- log(y[2:nob])-log(y[1:(nob-1)])           
Auto.VR(r)
```

> $stat [1] 2.202953
>     $sum [1] 1.153463

```
data(exrates)
y <- exrates$ca                                
nob <- length(y)
r <- log(y[2:nob])-log(y[1:(nob-1)])           
kvec <- c(2,5,10)
Lo.Mac(r,kvec)
```

> $Stats
>
> M1        M2
>
> k=2  2.5701993 2.0412787
>
> k=5  1.5517705 1.2834571
>
> k=10 0.3759064 0.3195872

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working to figure out my question. Then, I import the same data (above mentioned) to the python. I did this because I've found an explanation about the decision rule for at this link "http://arch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/unitroot/tests.html#variance-ratios" which says "*Rejection of the null with a positive test statistic indicates the presence of positive serial correlation in the time series.*"

here the r_NaN is the same as above mentioned series of "r" .

```
  from arch.unitroot import VarianceRatio
  vr_r = VarianceRatio(r_NaN, 2)
  print(vr_r.summary().as_text())
```

output:

```
     Variance-Ratio Test Results     
=====================================
Test Statistic                -20.527
P-value                         0.000
Lags                                2
-------------------------------------
```

And, the decision is: because the Test Statistic is negative we are not able to reject the null hyphotesis. Hence, we conclude that the series of r follows a random walk.